# Adding conditional targets to automake all and install targets

Tags: bash, autotools, automake

I've a conditional, `AM_CONDITIONAL`, clause that states if an optional component (with its own Makefile) should be built.

Thus, I've added the following statements to the parent `Makefile.am`.

```
if CAN_DOCS
docs: ; $(MAKE) -C ./docs all
endif
```

It would be great (and more portable) if I can override the `make all` target in some way to add a prereq to `docs` and an override to `make install` in turn to call `$(MAKE) -C ./docs install` on the same way.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two available approaches.

1. Conditionally append to the `SUBDIRS` variable to hook [Automake's recursive `make` capabilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Subdirectories.html):

   ```
   SUBDIRS =
   if CAN_DOCS
   SUBDIRS += docs
   endif
   ```

   The subdirectory need only have a `Makefile` (after configuration), not necessarily any autotooling at all.  However, the top-level `make` will in this case attempt to recurse into the subdirectory for *all* its recursive targets.  That could produce unwanted side effects if the subdirectory's makefile doesn't support all of those.  The Automake manual provides [a list](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Third_002dParty-Makefiles.html#Third_002dParty-Makefiles).
2. Use [`*-local` and / or `*-hook` targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html#Extending) to connect your custom rules to the standard targets.  You should be able to put such targets into conditional blocks, I think, but if that doesn't work then you can definitely achieve the wanted conditionality through the contents of `-local` and `-hook` targets' prerequisite lists.  Example:

   ```
   if CAN_DOCS
   all-local:
           $(MAKE) -C ./docs all
   endif
   ```